# Since John Herschel was first to make a photograph on a glass plate in 1839, why was the first astronomical photograph not taken until 1840 by Draper?

Tags: photography, history

Researching [Who named "the 37 cluster" or at least made that name widely known via writing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/57317/7982) I came across the Moneylink September, 9, 2020 article [9 September 1839: Sir John Herschel takes the first glass-plate photograph](https://moneyweek.com/336349/9-september-1839-herschel-takes-the-first-glass-plate-photograph)

> Frenchman Louis Daguerre is famous for inventing the daguerreotype – an early form of photography that used metal plates – in 1839. But on 9 September of that same year, our own Sir John Herschel created a photographic negative on a glass plate, using silver chloride. It is he who introduced the word “photography” into the English language.
>
> Herschel was one of the great Victorian polymaths, happy to turn his hand at almost anything. Besides his pioneering work in photography, he excelled at botany, maths, chemistry and the family hobby: astronomy. **His father was Sir William Herschel**, after whom the space observatory, which blasted off in 2009, is named.

The photograph is of *William* Herschel's telescope. So there's the photographic plate <s>and a nice big telescope</s> (oops, there's no telescope held within the iconic structure in this photograph), one looking at the other. And yet, the first astronomical photographic image didn't happen until the next year.

From [this answer to *First photographic image taken with telescopes to produce astronomically useful results? What telescope was used?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55909/7982):

> The first astronomical photo was of the moon, taken by John Draper in 1840, using the daguerreotype process itself.

(side note, Wikipedia's [John William Draper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_William_Draper) says:

> In March 1840 Draper became the second person to produce photographs of an astronomical object, the Moon, considered the first astrophotographs.<sup>15</sup>
>
> <sup>15</sup> Kalfus, Skye (2010). "Across the Spectrum". [Chemical Heritage Magazine. 28 (2)](https://digital.sciencehistory.org/works/o3vhms3). Chemical Heritage Foundation. Retrieved 23 March 2018.

**Question:** Since John Herschel was first to make a photograph on a glass plate in 1839 (and it was of an astronomical telescope!), why was the first astronomical photograph not taken until 1840, not with a glass plate ([daguerreotypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daguerreotype) used copper substrates), and instead by [John Draper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_William_Draper)?

[image: Herschel's 1839 photo of his father's telescope in Slough (Getty, via Moneylink 2022)]

> Herschel's 1839 photo of his father's telescope in Slough (Getty)

Comment: note that the question asks **both** why the first astronomical photo was not by one of the Herschels, and why it was not on a glass plate.

Comment: I don't get the question.  I suppose John never thought of attaching his camera to a telescope.  This is like asking "If touch screen technology existed in 2006 in Korea why didn't Samsung invent the iPhone?"   John probably could have taken a photograph of the moon, but he didn't.

Comment: @JamesK Wikipedia: [Sir John Frederick William Herschel, 1st Baronet KH FRS, 7 March 1792 – 11 May 1871) was an English polymath **active** as a mathematician, **astronomer**, chemist, inventor, and **experimental photographer** who invented the blueprint and did botanical work. Herschel **originated the use of the Julian day system in astronomy. He named seven moons of Saturn and four moons of Uranus – the seventh planet**, discovered by his father Sir William Herschel. **He made many contributions to the science of photography**...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Herschel)

Comment: @JamesK To such a person, active in both observational astronomy and photography, there must be some reason beyond "he never thought of it". If you have a telescope and a photographic plate, the [barrier to entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barriers_to_entry) for placing the plate at the focus of the telescope is a little bit lower than inventing and successfully building and marketing an iPhone. (There I go again with the [understatements](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/57236/automated-and-hopefully-free-systems-i-can-subscribe-to-sending-email-or-sms-t#comment130634_57236))

Comment: somewhat related: [Where did Wm. Herschel plan to put their head? Peer over the edge of the famous 40-foot telescope or try to get less off-axis; closer to the center?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/13196/3869)

Comment: Well, either he didn't think of it, or he was busy on other things at the time, and someone else happened to do it first.  Perhaps he thought "It's hard enough to get a photograph during the day,  I'll try to improve my method before thinking about night time photography."  I just don't think this requires any explanation.  I don't think there is any "deep" reason, like a belief that the moon was fundamentally unphotographable.

Comment: @JamesK I never heed "you shouldn't want to know the answer to your question" comments. Imagine if every user said that under every question they found disinteresting! I have a real hunch the answer will be informative and illuminating and my hunches are often (but not always) right. It may be tracking/exposure issues, it may be silver-on-glass vs daguerreotypes, it may be something else. And now that we know Draper's astrophotograph was the 2nd not the 1st maybe Herschel DID try! Let's just wait and see, rather than use the comment space to say "I don't think this is going to be interesting."

Comment: Oh sure, I'm just wondering if you have anything more than a hunch.  My hunch is that this won't get an answer because there is nothing to explain.  We shall see. Perhaps Herschel's laboratory notes are available and they give details of what exactly he was doing in the year 1839-1840.

Comment: Daguerre tried photographing the Moon before Draper did, but apparently the result was a blurry failure due to the Moon’s motion. (I think the first astronomically useful photographs were [those made of the Sun](https://sunearthday.nasa.gov/2006/locations/firstphoto.php) from the mid-1840s on.)

Comment: I find it rather astonishing that he was able to do that so early. From his Wikipedia page, just a year before he took portraits that "required the subject to keep his eyes closed due to the bright light."

Comment: Daguerreotypes had long exposure times.  There'd be little doubt that he actually tried, but success likely required significant modifications to the instruments.

Answer (score -1):

John Herschel took a photo in September and Draper took one the following March. That's only a 6-month interval at a time when photography didn't exist. You're asking why Herschel didn't think of doing everything at once.  There is no problem here.

On top of that, John Herschel who took the 1939 photo was a different person than William Herschel, the famous astronomer who discovered Uranus. John's early interest was photography and math, not astronomy.

William Herschel did very important things, but inventing astrophotography wasn't one of them.